# Create parameter for MAX allowed value SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am trying to create a parameter for a max allowed processing time, give it a 10 minutes value and then compare the processing times for other processes with the parameter value. This will include creating a new column where it will be mentioned if the parameter time is exceeded.

For this I am using the following:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(1000)
declare @ProcessTime int
declare @maxProcessTime int

set @sql = N'
SELECT ID, Type, Location, StartTime, EndTime, 
ProcessingTime = 
(CASE 
WHEN EndTime IS NULL then datediff(second, starttime, GETDATE())
ELSE datediff(second, starttime, endtime)
END),
ParameterExceeded = 
(CASE 
WHEN datediff(second, StartTime, EndTime) > 600 then ''YES''
ELSE  ''NO''
END )
FROM table1
set @maxProcessTime = 600
exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Table is something like this:

```
ID | Type  | Location | StartTime | EndTime |

1  | Type1 | 1        | 18:31     | 18:34   |
2  | Type2 | 2        | 18:35     | 18:50   |
```

Processing Time is calculated as the difference between start and end. `GETDATE` is being included for the fields displaying `NULL` values.

Please advise, thanks!

Comment: No need for that first `case` expression, simply do `datediff(second, starttime, coalesce(endtime,GETDATE())`.

Comment: You are hard coding the 600 and you don't need an exec sp_executesql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max);
declare @ProcessTime int;
declare @maxProcessTime int;
set @maxProcessTime = 600;

set @sql = N'
SELECT ID, Type, Location, StartTime, EndTime, 
       DATEDIFF(second, startTime, COALESCE(endTime, GETDATE())) as ProcessingTime,
       (CASE WHEN datediff(second, StartTime, COALESCE(endTime, GETDATE())) > @maxProcessTime then ''YES''
             ELSE  ''NO''
        END) as ParameterExceeded
FROM table1';

exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@maxProcessTime int', @maxProcessTime=@maxProcessTime;
```

Note that this uses the parameter in the subquery and passes it in using `sp_executesql`.

Answer (score 0):

You are not actually using `@maxProcessTime = 600`.  You don't need exec `sp_executesql`.

This works but does not do what you expect.  GetDate() could have a time that is before startTime.  GetDate() has no valid meaning in this context.

```
declare @T table (id int primary key, type varchar(10), startTime time not null, endTime time);
insert into @t values
       (1, 'Type1', '18:31', '18:34')
     , (2, 'Type2', '18:35', '18:50')
     , (3, 'Type2', '18:35', null)
     , (4, 'Type3', '3:35',  null);
declare @max int = 600;
declare @now time = getdate();
select @max as maxTime, @now as now; 

select tt.*
     , case when tt.diff < @max then 'yes' else 'no' end as madeIt
from ( select t.*
            , DATEDIFF(second, startTime, isnull(endTime, @now)) as diff
         from @T t
     ) tt
```